# Jquery how to reuse click function by giving a name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submitPollStudent">
```

I am using JQuery to implement clisk function as follows:

```
$("#submitPollStudent").click(function() {

 //my coding stuff comes here

});
```

I need to to implement the same function onclick on another function:

suppose:

```
if(flag == 0){
  $("#submitPollStudent").click();
}
```

How can Re use the function?

I tried something like this:

I modified click function as:

```
$("#submitPollStudent").click(function myfunc() {

     //my coding stuff comes here

    })

//for calling
if(flag == 0){
      myfunc();
    }
```

In case of javascript I can do like this:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submitPollStudent" onclick="myfun()">
   function myfun() {

     //my coding stuff comes here
}

   //for calling
    if(flag == 0){
          myfunc();
        }
```

How can I implement the same in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead on creating function inside click just create simple function.

```
function myfunction()
{
  // your code here 
}


$("#submitPollStudent").click(function() {
     myfunction();
});


if(flag == 0){
  myfunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the named function as follow.

See the comments in the code.

```
// Define myFunc
function myFunc(e) {
    // Function body here
}

// Use myFunc as click handler
$("#submitPollStudent").click(myFunc);
```

You can call it as normal function.

```
if(flag == 0){
    // Call it as myFunc()
    myFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a name in a function expression doesn't make it a function declaration, it's still a function expression and the name is only visible inside that function.

Move the function out of the expression to make it a function declaration, then you can use the name in both the event binding and the function call:

```
function myfunc() {

    //my coding stuff comes here

}

$("#submitPollStudent").click(myfunc);

//for calling
if(flag == 0){
    myfunc();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Define the function outside the jQuery parameter:
Like this

```
function myfunc() {

     //my coding stuff comes here

}
$("#submitPollStudent").click(myfunc);

//for calling
if(flag == 0){
    myfunc();
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? What is wrong with this answer? Did i make a mistake anywhere?